# The video recorded by opencv VideoWriter is not playing at a uniform speed

Tags: opencv, video, record

I use opencv's videowriter to record the video, but when I play the video, the picture is not always at a constant speed. Sometimes it will be faster, but it will become normal later. For example,if there is a person walking in the video, the person sometimes walks very fast, but he will slow down later and then walk faster again. But In fact, the person is walking at a constant speed. Could someone tell me how to solve the problem? Any comments are welcome. Thanks

Here is my record code:

```
def image_callback(msg):
    self.image_queue.put(msg)


fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("test.avi",fourcc,30,(1280,720))
while (True):
    if(self.image_queue.qsize() > 0):
        out.write(self.image_queue.get())#self.image_queue is a queue which keep storing cv::mat data
```

Answer (score 0):

Think it like VideoWriter puts a constant delay between each frame it gets (1000/30 ms in your case). The problem is that your image callback does not get input at equally-spaced time intervals. A solution may be as following:

- Measure the time passed between two images that are coming from the callback (Let `time_passed` be this variable in milliseconds).
- Insert `round(time_passed / (1000/30.))` frames to VideoWriter.

If this does not look good either, like if people are pausing at some moment, you may increase the FPS for a smoother result. Anyway, this approach is heavily dependent on runtime and you will probably get undesired results at CPU overloads, but I do not not any better approach without a prior information about the images coming from the callback.